# Need to handle one to many in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to handle one to many situation. Below is a very close scenario which I am facing.

The scenario is: `Car` can have many `Owners`, but a single owner at any point in time. Entities are shown below for idea with minimum information.

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string nic { get; set; }
}
```

Business model:

```
public class CarOwner
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerNIC { get; set; }
}
```

If the NIC is changed, I want to insert a new row into `Car` owners.

Answer (score 0):

Does your car always have an owner or can a car have a history of owner and no current owner? If your car has always one owner, you could make a child collection `History` that has three properties `CarId`, `OwnerId` and `Timestamp`. The current owner would than always the entry with the highest timestamp.

If it could be possible, that a car has a history of owner, but no current owner, you should add a property `CurrentOwnerId` to the car that could be null, thous making it possible to have a car with a history of old owners, but no current owner.

Comment: I am mainting the timestamp in the owners table. But i did not show.. I want to ask is if a request comes with a car having a new NIC then how  should i insert a new row in Owners table else i will update details with the owners table

Answer (score 0):

if you do the following

```
public class Car
{
 public int CarId{ get; set; }
 public Owner CurrentOwner { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Owner> PreviousOwners { get; set; }
}
```

EF will sort out the Many to Many mapping between the 2 entities. You will have to do the NIC change adding a new owner thing yourself in your business layer as that seems like a business rule instead.

Comment: How will you manage if an existing car comes with new owner information. I want if CurrentOwner information is changed then add a new owner. Old one will come in PreviousOwners.

Comment: You cannot solve that with only the data model. Since it is a rule your application has, your business logic of updating cars and owners need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

> If the NIC is changed, I want to insert a new row into Car owners.

I create a simple demo which submits the `CarOwner` from view and insert a new `Owner`.

Model:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string nic { get; set; }
}

public class CarOwner
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string OwnerNIC { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestCar([Bind("CarID,OwnerNIC")] CarOwner carOwner )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var owner = new Owner()
            {
                CarId = carOwner.CarID,
                nic = carOwner.OwnerNIC
            };
            _context.Add(owner);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(carOwner);
    }
```